# Use of numeric ids in Activity xml description and by code

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

I use id in xml:

```
Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="438dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="110dp" android:id="@+id/a11"/>
```

Then I want to retrieve the object in Java code with an iteration over all buttons. Previously, I use numeric id and do it so:

```
  for (int i = 20; i < 24; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(i);
```

But that is not correct. It gives error in R generated class.

```
public static final int 11=0x49279429;
```

So I put a letter before the numeric id: "a11"

But how to retrieve Button in a loop:

```
findViewById(R.id.(loop increment variable ????)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
int Id = getResources().getIdentifier("radioButtonId" ,"id",getPackageName());
```

to  get the id and use

```
 RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(Id);
```